# How to change the position of a UIButton dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uibutton

I have a group of 31 buttons in a IBOutletCollection,

This is to create a calendar (i.e) the number of days in a month, I have to change the  position of these buttons depending on the 1st days week day, that looks like a calendar.

I am not able to add target-action mechanism when I write code to implement the same in Xcode 4.2, so I tried do'g it in the Interface Builder using IBOutlet Collection.

But now the question is how do I change the postion of these bottons each one representing the               one day of the month?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405609/uibutton-changing-position/30748100#30748100

Answer (score 2):

You can change the position like so:

```
myButton.frame = CGRectMake( x, y, width, height );
```

eg.

```
myButton.frame = CGRectMake( 20, 20, 100, 50 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your calendar is for - but you might want to check out an open source iPhone calendar, it's pretty good: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/kal

You could either just use it as it is, or look at how it's implemented and use that to help you develop yours.

Answer (score -1):

For changing the position, use the `center` property of that button.

For example:

```
theButton.center = CGPointMake(10.0f, 10.0f);
```

Comment: Which part of this answer did not work, so I can correct or delete it?