# UIButton Changing Position

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, iphone-5

I have a button set up in IB. I have an IBOutlet set up and the onscreen object linked to it. Is there a way to programmatically change that buttons position and/or size? I know you can change the title and some things but I don't see how to change it's position or size.

[image]

Now I would like to change the position of it accordingly. Is it possible? If yes, please let me know how, since I am trying to change the position of my button in the following code, but it does not work in the header file.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *mybuttonOutlet;
```

In the implementation file:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {


    screenSizeHeight=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;


if(screenSizeHeight==568)

    mybuttonOutlet.frame= CGRect(38, 464 ,157,25);


if(screenSizeHeight==480)

    mybuttonOutlet.frame= CGRect(38, 364 ,157,25);

}
```

Comment: did you connect this myButtonOutlet with your .xib ?

Comment: I don't find any reason why this won't work unless you forgot to connect the IBOutlet.

Comment: yes, I connected my button to my .xib

Comment: Just a wild guess, did you connect multiple outlets to the same button?

Comment: No just only one outlet to my button.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove `Use Autolayout` from the button in IB or storyboard.

Comment: I believe you can only remove autolayout from the entire xib/SB itself - which worked for me too.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to adjust positions with Autolayout enabled, you will have to change your code like this

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    screenSizeHeight=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

    if(screenSizeHeight==568)
        mybuttonOutlet.frame= CGRect(38, 464 ,157,25);

    if(screenSizeHeight==480)
        mybuttonOutlet.frame= CGRect(38, 364 ,157,25);
}
```

Basically you need to perform any custom layout adjustments in viewDidLayoutSubviews method if Autolayout is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Please perform this check.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    if(self.mybuttonOutlet==nil)NSLog(@"Button is NIL");
}
```

Now if you get the log "Button is NIL", then probably you forgot to link your IB button to your variable mybuttonOutlet.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end


#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *theButton;


// -(IBAction)moveTheButton:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize theButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)moveTheButton:(id)sender{
    //set default position
    CGRect btFrame = theButton.frame;
    btFrame.origin.x = 145;
    btFrame.origin.y = 285;
    theButton.frame = btFrame;

    //position changing
    btFrame.origin.x += 40;
    theButton.frame = btFrame;

    //new size of button
    CGRect rect=CGRectMake(145, 285, 190, 30);
    [self.theButton setBounds:rect];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually went for the constraints. Get an outlet of the constraints that determine the position of the button (top, bottom, leading, trailing) and change the constraint(s) value(s).

```
self.constBtnSubmitTrailing.constraint = 50.0
```

This so you can keep AutoLayout enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I figured out for this is to create new View object inside the main View, and put my "dynamically changing objects" inside that View (as shown in picture).

[Object hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9RXu.png)

Then I use Auto-Layout to position the new View in the main View.
But bugButton:UIButton which is inside the new View, changes position as expected with:

```
bugButton.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: newX, y: newY)
```